# How to check if a user has a subscription (Android in-app billing)?

Tags: android, google-api, in-app-billing, google-play, subscription

I've been trying to use the Google Play Android Developer API but just realized that that might not be what I should be doing:

> Your servers should never query subscription status dynamically, based
>   on individual requests from your Android application. -[Google](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#play-dev-api)

I don't have my own servers and don't anticipate over 15000 daily app uses (the API allows 15000 requests per day), and was just planning on checking the subscription state every time the app is started up.

This seems to be what Google is saying I should *not* be doing. So, how can I check a user's subscription state otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the answer is a couple of paragraphs above in the [same document](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#play-dev-api) :

> - Store subscription expiry on your servers
> - Cache expiration and purchaseState
> - Query for subscription status only at expiration

Generally, what they are saying is that you should cache the state of subscription and don't query it each time.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have servers.

Comment: I think it's still applicable. At the start of your application you can do HTTP request to get subscription status. However, if thousands of users will start it hundreds times a day - you will be in trouble (exceed 15000 limitation). So, you can do this request once when your app starts and cache expiration and status on the device and do request again, only at expiration.

Comment: One thing which bothers me in NOT having server is security. You will need authenticate and authorize to do these calls. This mean that you will have to hardcode access token or something like that, which isn't very good idea (anybody can reverse engineer your app).

Comment: What if my users are so much that they all expires at the same day? I think they should just simply remove this limitation. That would be more easier to implement this feature.

Comment: @KimiChiu I believe for last 4 years (from the moment when this question was asked) they bumped up API limit to 200k requests. If you truly need to do more requests than that you can always contact Google and I am pretty sure that can bump it this limit for your app even higher.

Comment: @VictorRonin Thanks! I found it here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/developer-api.html#quota

Comment: hi, I am stuck into a typical issue.When a user purchased a subscription, api failed to retrieve any info of that transaction that are suppose to stored onto our servers. Now this user is unable to access paid features of app, as there is no such info about purchase onto our servers, also this user is unable to re-purchase that subscription as he is already subscribed, google throws error already subscribed. Is there anyway to resolve this particular issue?

Comment: you need to use google developer api to verify the purchase first